# How to update a page with an external weblink, keeping the navbar fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are trying to show some popular websites in custom page of ours. We added some buttons with relevant links, and when clicked on them it should redirect to that website, while being shown on the same page of ours.

Is there any work around about it?

Our approach was, to put a click event for each button, then append a iframe with it. However most of the websites can't be shown on a frame.

```
<button id = "google"></button>
<div id ="googledisplay"></div>

var google = document.getElementbyId("google");
$("#google").one("click", function(e) {
    $("#googledisplay").append('<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>');
});
```

Seems like google can't be displayed in an iFrame. Any suggestion, guidance are welcomed.

Comment: Maybe... `$('#div').load('your-link');` ? — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/1uz6o0sf/

Comment: You can not load google in an iframe as google set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' which means no one else can call their site in iFrame.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, did tried that, but page returned with no logo and search box. Targeting IE11 as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most websites will deny a request to have their site on an iframe as part of another site. When you try creating an `<iframe>` of the google site the browser will deny it because of their `X-Frame-Options` header. The error in the Chrome console will read:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

TLDR: Very few websites allow this behavior and it is simply not  the right way to do something like this.

Edit: To answer the second part of your question, their is no practical workaround to this. If something like this is found in a browser, it will be treated as a bug and patched immediatly. It is simply a matter of security.